# Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'admin')

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, ejs

Hi i am getting this error when i am trying to restructure the project as MVC. I am creating usecases in my models. So i am trying to get my structure like this: When a route is hit, it goes to the controller and then from the controller it looks up to the usecase.My index router file :

```
"use strict";
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const TodoTask = require("../models/entity/ToDoTask");
const {
  ensureAuthenticated,
  forwardAuthenticated,
} = require("../controller/authentication/index");

const { isAdmin } = require("../controller/authentication/adminAuthMiddleware");

const todos = require("../controller/todos/index");
const {
  getAllTodos,
  createTodo,
  getTodo,
  editTodo,
  deleteTodo,
} = require("../controller/todos/index");

// Welcome Page
router.get("/", forwardAuthenticated, (req, res) => res.render("landing"));
router.get("/dashboard", ensureAuthenticated, getAllTodos);
router.get("/admin-dashboard", ensureAuthenticated, getAllTodos);
router.post("/dashboard", createTodo);
router.route("/edit/:id").get(getTodo).post(editTodo);
router.route("/remove/:id").get(deleteTodo);

router.get("/admin-dashboard", isAdmin, (req, res) =>
  res.render("admin-dashboard")
);

module.exports = router;
```

I am creating a controller for getting all the todos

```
const TodoTask = require("../../models/entity/ToDoTask");
const TODOS = require("../../models/usecases/todo");
module.exports = {
getAllTodos: async () => {
try {
      console.log("in the controller");
      let todos = await TODOS.getAllTodos({});
      return todos;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  },
```

and the error that i am getting is in the usecase

```
const TodoTask = require("../../models/entity/ToDoTask");

const getAllTodos = async function (req, res) {
  if (req.user.admin === true) {
    TodoTask.find({}, (err, tasks) => {
      res.render("admin-dashboard.ejs", {
        todoTasks: tasks,
        user: req.user,
      });
    });
  } else {
    TodoTask.find({ "user.id": req.user._id }, (err, tasks) => {
      res.render("todo.ejs", {
        todoTasks: tasks,
        user: req.user,
      });
      console.log(tasks);
    });
  }
};
```

so i am getting error as 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'admin') in models\usecases\todo.js
Please help

Comment: So, for whatever reason, when `req.user.admin` is referenced, `req.user` is undefined. Hard to say, but probably due the asynchronicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your function `getAllTodos` with below code.
If the `req` object has `user` object and in further it has `admin` as `true`, it should work as expected.

```
const TodoTask = require("../../models/entity/ToDoTask");
const TODOS = require("../../models/usecases/todo");
module.exports = {
    getAllTodos: async (req, res) => {
    try {
          console.log("in the controller");
          let todos = await TODOS.getAllTodos(req, res);
          return todos;
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
        }
     },
}
```

Edit:
Modify your function from todo as below,

```
const TodoTask = require("../../models/entity/ToDoTask");

const getAllTodos = async function (req, res) {
  if (req.user.admin === true) {
    TodoTask.find({}, (err, tasks) => {
      return res.render("admin-dashboard.ejs", {
        todoTasks: tasks,
        user: req.user,
      });
    });
  } else {
    TodoTask.find({ "user.id": req.user._id }, (err, tasks) => {
     return res.render("todo.ejs", {
        todoTasks: tasks,
        user: req.user,
      });
      console.log(tasks);
    });
  }
};
```